# Unix locate command for present working directory

Tags: unix, command

The [locate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_%28Unix%29) command in Unix will return the path related to the attribute given (for example, `locate abc_file`). What is the command to locate a file in the present working directory structure?

Answer (score 10):

If you use wildcards (as `*`) `locate` considers the pattern to be an absolute path. Therefore you could e.g. do:

```
locate "$PWD*/abc_file"
```

This will find all files `abc_file` under your `$PWD` and its subfolders (as long as they are in the locate database).

Answer (score 9):

On the other hand you can also always use oldschool [find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find):

```
find . -name abc_file
```